# Eagle clearance issue

Tags: eaglecad, layout

I don't know how to search this problem on google so I was hoping you guys could help out.

I have made an eagle part by myself. I have used the top layer for the pads (just click pad and then adjust size) and I used 21 layer for the package width and stuff. Now I also get a clearance under and around the package with the 21 layer. Does anybody know how to fix it? It is quite strange because the bottom ground plane also gets affected by this. See picture:

[image: Edit: with bottom I mean in this case top because the part is on the bottom. In other words, it affects both planes]

Comment: are you sure you didnt draw anything on any other layer? try running "display all" to see if there arent any hidden objects in this part

Comment: No sorry, I tried. There is nothing on another layer.

Comment: I think it has something to do with isolation of the 21 layer. But why does the silkscreen layer has an isolation? And I have no clue where to change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the problem. I will state below what the solution is so that others can learn from it:

- I started drawing the package with the dimension layer.. I know, don't do that.
- Then I replaced the layer with the silkscreen 21 tplace layer. This is the layer that should be used if the component outline should be visible on the final PCB.
- What I should have done is updating my library. I thought I did this, but probably failed to double check.

Now everything works fine. Thanks for the support.

Comment: Just a serve warning: The dimension layer tells the manufacturer where to place cuts on the PCB. A single line in this layer left yon your board, and he will pull a milling head though it.

Comment: Really? Well thanks. Did not know that it was that important. Thanks for notifying me :)